# How to retrieve all items of firebase realtime database

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve all children of Order child, but I assigned them random ids before so how to retrieve children without knowing ids?

I mean while inserting data:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int id = rnd.Next(10, 1000);

var data = new Data {
    customer_id = textbox1.Text,
    food =textbox2.Text
};
SetResponse res = await client.SetTaskAsync("Order/"+id.toString(), data); Data result = res.ResultAs();
```

But while retrieving data:

```
FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetTaskAsync("Order/????");
Data obj = response.ResultAs<Data>();

textbox3.Text=obj.food;
```